# Push TableViewController from a UICollectionView with UITableViewCell's

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

So I am trying to push a UITableViewController from a UITableViewCell that is embedded in a collection view cell.

So the structure is UICollectionView > UICollectionViewCell > UITableView > UITableViewCell.

Do I want to call a segue when the TableViewCell is clicked?

How can I do this as you cannot access the function perform segue for identifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create one `protocol` for that and implement it with your ViewController where you are having `collectionView`, after that make instance property of that protocol in your `collectionViewCell` and set that property in `cellForItemAt` method. Now inside the `didSelectRowAt` method of `tableView` call the delegate method with the detail that you want to pass for segue.

```
protocol PassData {
    func performSegue(with data: String) //Set argument type to Type that you want pass instead of String         
}
```

Now implement this `PassData` protocol with your `ViewController` and inside the `cellForItemAt` set the delegate of `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PassData, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
    //Other methods         

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell
        cell.passDelegate = self
        return cell
    }

    //Add the `performSegue(with:)` delegate method of PassData
    func performSegue(with data: String)  {
        //Perform segue here
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "SegueIdentifier", sender: data)
    }
}
```

Now in your `CustomCollectionViewCell` make one instance property named `passDelegate` of type `PassData?` after that in `didSelectRowAt` method of tableView call its delegate method.

```
class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

     var passDelegate: PassData?

     //Your other methods

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //Pass whatever data that you want to pass
        self.passDelegate?.performSegue(with: array[indexPath.row]) 
    }         
}
```

Comment: One word. Legend.

Answer (score 0):

You can push the tableViewController to navigation stack by calling `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(tableviewVC, animate: true)` from table view delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`